# PKWARE Strong Encryption Algorithm

Tags: encryption, zip, pkware

I wonder about **PKWARE Strong Encryption algorithm**.

[ZIP File Format Specification v6.3.5](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm/blob/master/src/test/resources/ZIP%20File%20Format%20Specification%20v6.3.5.txt) says about **Strong Encryption by PKWARE** (*7.0 Strong Encryption Specification*). This description is not completed and it's impossible to implement this encryption in the application.

I wonder about is there any working source code using this encryption algorithm? Does not matter what language. I'm planning to add it to my own application but did not succeed yet.

> **P.S.** This is not a Traditional PKWARE Encryption, that described in *6.0  Traditional PKWARE Encryption*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no open source implementations.

The strong encryption functionality is patented. If you have not already done so, contact zipformat@pkware.com to obtain a license.

After you have a license, if you provide more details about what you think is missing from the description, I can try to help.

Source: I'm an engineer at PKWARE

Comment: Will it be against the patent in case I implement 3des encryption and decryption by myself using open sources to be able to work with these archives not using Pkware Secure ZiP tool?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. The folks that monitor that email account are the ones to ask. I encourage you to send those questions there.

I wish I could be more helpful here on SO, but since I am speaking as an individual, not as a representative of PKWARE, all I can do is recommend that you go through the official channels to get answers about licensing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I faced with this issue, I definitely contact the support.

Comment: MariusVolkhart, I have written to `zipformat@pkware.com` but no answer. Could you check is this email still actual? Thank you.