# What's the Zip Strong Encryption Specification/SecureZip key derivation function?

Tags: encryption, zip, aes, winzip, pkzip

In the (PK)ZIP specification at https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT, specifically in the Strong Encryption Specification (SES) section, there is a line on deriving a key from a password:

```
MasterSessionKey = DeriveKey(SHA1(Password))
```

What's `DeriveKey`?

(In WinZip's AES documentation at https://www.winzip.com/en/support/aes-encryption/, they use PBKDF2 with 1000 iterations. I don't see any similar explanation in APPNOTE)

Answer (score 1):

`PKWARE` implemented a **strong encryption** in version 5, but did not provide the algorithm of encoding/decoding ([Method For Strongly Encrypted .ZIP Files - Patent US 2020/0250329 A1](https://www.freepatentsonline.com/20200250329.pdf)). In this algorithm [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption was implemented as part of it. You can define this by **strong encryption (bit 6) = yes** in **General Purpose Flag**.

After that `WinZip` could not use this algo, so it invented another one. You can define this by **strong encryption (bit 6) = no** in **General Purpose Flag** and **AesExtraFieldRecord** with **signature 0x990**.

As you can see there're two ways to encrypt a `zip` file. All open source software use the second one. The first one is available only by [PKWARE SecureZIP](https://download.cnet.com/SecureZIP/3000-2092_4-10191865.html)

You can find example of this alogirthm in [(7zip) Strong.cpp:35](https://github.com/keithjjones/7z/blob/174a5af5960d2bbebc7deb3b7bc622f5f62b9a3e/CPP/7zip/Crypto/ZipStrong.cpp). In `java` it should look like this:

```java
public static byte[] getMasterKey(String password) {
    byte[] data = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] sha1 = DigestUtils.sha1(data);
    return DeriveKey(sha1);
}

private static byte[] DeriveKey(byte[] digest) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[kDigestSize * 2];  // kDigestSize = 20
    DeriveKey2(digest, (byte)0x36, buf, 0);
    DeriveKey2(digest, (byte)0x5C, buf, kDigestSize);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, 0, 32);
}

private static void DeriveKey2(byte[] digest, byte c, byte[] dest, int offs) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[64];
    Arrays.fill(buf, c);

    for (int i = 0; i < kDigestSize; i++)
        buf[i] ^= digest[i];

    byte[] sha1 = DigestUtils.sha1(buf);
    System.arraycopy(sha1, 0, dest, offs, sha1.length);
}
```

**Demo:**

```java
String password = "JohnDoe";
byte[] masterKey = getMasterKey(password);
```

Comment: I have similar post https://stackoverflow.com/q/58393996/3461397 and there there're the answer from PKWARE guy.

Comment: Thanks for this - although to clarify, is the code here an example of PKWARE's algorithm or WinZip's?

Comment: Ah... [nosing around the code](https://github.com/keithjjones/7z/blob/174a5af5960d2bbebc7deb3b7bc622f5f62b9a3e/CPP/7zip/Archive/Zip/ZipHandler.cpp#L555), I think it's PKWARE's(?). I'm wondering though, are there potential patent/licensing issues here?

Comment: I think yes. At least for encoding, because PKWARE SecureZip is not free. But there is SecureZipReader - it is free. I think in case you implement StringEncryption Reading in your application, it could be norm. I am think about support reading in my zip4jvm - 
 https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm as well.

Comment: I have requested an information from Pkware. The said that there is not limits to implemente any part of zip format specification until you not use Pkwares's applications.

Answer (score 0):

The next paragraph 'defines' it

> 7.2.5.3 The function names and parameter requirements will depend on
> the choice of the cryptographic toolkit selected.  Almost any
> toolkit supporting the reference implementations for each
> algorithm can be used.  The RSA BSAFE(r), OpenSSL, and Microsoft
> CryptoAPI libraries are all known to work well.

I guess it's up to you to decide which of the encryption algorithms you want to use and go from there